# why am I getting errors when I use different backgrounds in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-intent

I have 3 activities which I want to use different backgrounds with. but when i do this i get this i get this error however if i only use different backgrounds on 2 activities then the app works

11-20 13:40:25.855: E/AndroidRuntime(849): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.medepad.community_virtual_ward/com.medepad.community_virtual_ward.Temperature}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class

the activities are called main welcome and temperature.

code for main
xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/main" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="400dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

java code

```
package com.medepad.community_virtual_ward;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    int a;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView start = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        start.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent welcome= new Intent (this,Welcome.class);
        startActivity(welcome);
    }
}
```

code for temperature

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/temperature" >

</LinearLayout>
```

java code

```
package com.medepad.community_virtual_ward;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Temperature extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.temperature);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

welcome xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/welcome" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="400dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

java code

```
package com.medepad.community_virtual_ward;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Welcome extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
        TextView next= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent temperature= new Intent(this, Temperature.class);
        startActivity(temperature);
    }
}
```

why am i getting this error and what can i do to use the amount of backgrounds i want?

Comment: Can you post the code please?

Comment: Post your XML and any relevant code

Comment: i have done can you help

Comment: please try to remove the space between "<" and "LinearLayout" in the "temperature" file and see if that helps.

Comment: Do you have drawable resources with name "main" and "temperature" under "res/..."?

Comment: Is the "temperature" drawable an XML file or a graphic?

Comment: the temperature drawable is an xml file and i have those pictures in my resources folder

Comment: sorry guys i gave you the code for the one that works i have now edited it to the one that doesnt work. the difference is you will notice the backgrounds for each xml file is set to a different png file in my drawable folder. can you help me?

Comment: I think the error is in your temperature drawable xml file. Can you share that? Your description of the problem is confusing. I can't tell what is actually different between your working code and non-working code from your description.

Comment: what is it you dont understand tenfour04. I have 3 different xml files with three different backgrounds. Main is the launch activity then it goes to welcome then temperature. when i set each xml file to a different background it gives the error above before it opens temperature. However when i set temperature to have the same background as one of the earlier activities that gets launched the app works. so my issue is why does android not let me use more than 2 different backgrounds without giving me the error above?

Comment: OK, so you're assuming that setting more than 2 different backgrounds is what is causing your problem. But I think that is an incorrect assumption. I think what's actually causing the problem is that your temperature background drawable xml file is corrupt. You need to share that file for us to identify what's wrong. I think you can safely remove all the above code from your post, because the error is not in that code.

Answer (score 0):

The end of your first XML file has an extra `>`.

Comment: which file are you refering to as the first one called main runs properly and does not help me answer my question. sorry guys i gave you the code for the one that works i have now edited it to the one that doesnt work. the difference is you will notice the backgrounds for each xml file is set to a different png file in my drawable folder. can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following file

> temperature.xml

Make sure, it has following contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/temperature" >

</LinearLayout>
```

and you have either defined a drawable resource with name `temperature.xml` and `main.xml` under `res/drawable` folder or you have added image resources with name `temperature` and `main` in your Android project.

Comment: sorry guys i gave you the code for the one that works i have now edited it to the one that doesnt work. the difference is you will notice the backgrounds for each xml file is set to a different png file in my drawable folder. can you help me?