# what type of images cause a java.lang.outofmemoryerror?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-listview

I have created an android project that has 3 xml files. Main Welcome and Temperature. When the app launches you click on a button in main to take you to welcome then a button in welcome to take you to temperature. Each xml file has a different background. but when I click the button in welcome to take me to temperature i get the out of memory error. this is discussed in this link.
[why am I getting errors when I use different backgrounds in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097702/why-am-i-getting-errors-when-i-use-different-backgrounds-in-xml?noredirect=1#comment30041705_20097702)

I solved this issue when i realized my background images were too big. the screen size i was using was 1024X600 and the images i was using as my background were 1300X724. So i changed the sizes and the app worked however when i made more xml files with the same concept. different backgrounds but with the new size of image 1024X600 the further down the activities i got, the same error appeared.

So why do i get this error when i have change the images to match the screen size? and is there a certain size of image i must use? what does this error mean?

Comment: It means (as obvious as it seems) you're running out of memory. You are probably holding more than one bitmap in memory at any given time so each time the system is requested to load another image you simply run out of memory. Remove the references to previous bitmaps when switching backgrounds and it should work.

Comment: not knowing the android world, I would say there is a limited amount of memory space to store the images. Not in pixels, in Bytes. You should try with a light weight image... or maybe you simply need to dispose of some variables in your code, but as you don't show it...