# how to clear memory when it is full because of using too many backgrounds in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, logcat, android-logcat

Hi guys i am new to android and i posted a question a week ago in this link which basically stated that i was getting a java.lang.outofmemory error when i was using a lot of different backgrounds for my activities.
[why am I getting errors when I use different backgrounds in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097702/why-am-i-getting-errors-when-i-use-different-backgrounds-in-xml?noredirect=1#comment30041705_20097702)

So as a new developer I have searched and searched for a solution as to how to clear the memory as i go from activity but none have been clear or precise. Then i stumbled across this site http://androidactivity.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/solution-for-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget/

which described exactly what i was going through except they use 10 activities and i am only using 4. However when i implemented his code it my project i ended up with null pointer exceptions and after fiddling with his code I ended up back were i started with the same out of memory error. 
So can anybody direct me to someone who can show me how to have as many backgrounds as i want with out running out of memory. Or does android  as great as it is does not let you simply use more than a certain amount of backgrounds? help?

Answer (score 1):

It's not that there is a limit on the amount of backgrounds, but each background image you load is a loaded into memory as a bitmap and held there until the activity is destroyed. If you are opening multiple activities one after another, each background image will need to be held in memory and so eventually you will get an out of memory exception.

If you set a large background image, you will also experience some blocking on the ui thread, while the image is loaded into memory.

One way around this that worked for me was to use an imageloader. This decodes the image off the ui thread, caches it on disk, loads it into memory and if memory is running low, will clear an image from memory and fallback to the disk cache. You may get a slight delay/fade in as the image is loaded but this is not so bad visually, and when loaded once, will load straight away if you go back to that activity.

Check out Picaso [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) which is really easy to implement and a great api or [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

My layouts were all RelativeLayouts and the first child (will be behind all other views) was an ImageView with scaleType centercrop and width and height set to match_parent. When each activity loads (onCreate), just grab a reference to the imageview in your layout and set the required background image using your ImageLoader of choice.

The other option is to have multiple copies of your background image in your resources, with each one resized to perfectly fit your resolutions of choice (drawable-mdpi/-hdpi/-xhdpi etc). This way, you ensure you are never loading images that are way bigger than you need to be displayed and your app will be more forgiving in terms of memory consumption.